# Show that $|f(a)| < sup \{|f(x) | : x \in A \}$ for every $a \in A^{\circ}$.

Tags: general-topology

> > Let $X$ be  any space and $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ an open mapping. Denote the distance of $f(x) \in \mathbb R^n$ to the origin by $|f(x) |$ . Let $A \subset X$ be any set. Show that $|f(a)| < sup \{|f(x) | : x \in A \}$ for every $a \in A^{\circ}$.

Let $ a \in A^{\circ}$, then $\exists$  $B_r(a) $ such that $B_r(a) \subset A$

$\therefore B_r(f(a)) \subset f(A)$

Please tell me further how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: try to do in this way.. prove that $\sup-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 1):

**First,** it is not correct that $B_r(f(a)) \subset f(A)$. The fact that $f$ is open implies that $f(B_r(a))$ is open, and therefore there exists a ball $$B_{r'}(f(a)) \subset f(B_r(a)) \subset f(A)$$
but the new radius is in general distinct.

Now, **for the rest of the proof** prove that for any ball $B_R(z) \subset \mathbb R^n$ there exists some $x \in B_R(z)$ such that $|z| < |x|$. To do this, try to pick $x= \alpha z$ for some $\alpha$. You need to pick $\alpha$ in such a way that $|z|<|x|$ and $\alpha z \in B_R(z)$, this is easy.

Comment: @ N.S : I am agree your arguement , how to conclude the final result

Comment: @user120386 Well if you can find some $y \in B_{r'}(f(a)) \subset f(B_r(a)) \subset f(A)$ with $|f(z)| <|y|$, since $y \in f(A)$ it follows that $y=f(x)$ for some $x$. And then $|f(z)| <|f(x)|$.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply